# JQuery plugin for zoom in and out

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Is there JQuery plugin used to instant zoom in and zoom out effect on an image like in clicking the "like" button on post of [getglue.com](http://getglue.com) or the way facebook mobile app show it when you like something?

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-image-galleries-sliders-best-of/

Comment: you can also use jquery dialouge if you want simle img or div open on click

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin called **Zoomooz.js** that can zoom/expand elements on the page.

You can find that plugin here: http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/

I believe that what getblue.com has implemented is custom, and could be easily achieved with some basic jQuery.  Just google around on how to expand/contract elements using jQuery.  There are hundreds of examples from you to learn from.

Comment: i am not talking about the overlay lightbox. When u click any like button on getglue, the thumb on right suddenly zooms out and zooms in instantaneously. I am looking for that effect

Comment: You might try Zoomooz.js.  Other than that, I think their implementation is custom and would take pretty basic jQuery to achieve.  Just google around on how to expand/contract elements in jQuery.  There are tons of examples.  http://janne.aukia.com/zoomooz/